# Postgres service not getting up due to SSL error

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to run Nominatim api which is publicaly available,

https://github.com/mediagis/nominatim-docker/tree/master/4.2

And keep getting this error,

/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/14/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1

> textPayload: "2024-03-18 13:48:05.347 UTC [40] FATAL:  could not load
> server certificate file "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem": SSL
> error code 2147483650"

I tried various related solutions available on stackoverflow but nothing worked so far.
Any lead will be appreciated.